# C++: strange missing ';' before error, due to a typedef'ed return type in templated class

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, typedef

I am getting a very confusing compiler error when building the following test code.

```
f:\data\sdks\smctc-1.00\examples\ik_pf\msvc\MarkerSampler.inl(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'MarkerSampler<MarkerT>::sample2'
f:\data\sdks\smctc-1.00\examples\ik_pf\msvc\MarkerSampler.inl(16): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Note sample builds without error, but sample2 is causing the problem. The only difference being one explicitly details the return type without the use of a typedef and the other uses the typdef'ed version.

.h file

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __MARKERSAMPLER_H_INCLUDED__
#define __MARKERSAMPLER_H_INCLUDED__

#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <qthread.h>

#include <Wm5Vector3.h>
#include "UtilityFunctions.h"
#include "Marker.h"
#include "MarkerSet.h"

template <class MarkerT>
class MarkerSampler : public QThread
{


  typedef std::vector<MarkerT> MarkerVector ;
  typedef MarkerSet<MarkerT> MarkerSetT ;
  typedef std::vector<MarkerSetT> MarkerSetVector ;

public :

 MarkerSampler(const std::string inputDataDirectory, const unsigned int nSamples, const unsigned int startFrame, const unsigned int nFramesToUse) : 
    inputDataDirectory_(inputDataDirectory), nSamples_(nSamples), startFrame_(startFrame), nFramesToUse_(nFramesToUse) {seed = -time(NULL) ;}

 ~MarkerSampler() {}

 std::vector<MarkerSet<MarkerT> > sample(const double scaleFactor = 1.0, const double noiseSD = 0.0) ;

 MarkerSetVector sample2(const double scaleFactor = 1.0, const double noiseSD = 0.0) ;

protected:
 void run();

private:

 int seed ;

 const std::string inputDataDirectory_ ;
 const unsigned int nSamples_ ;
 const unsigned int startFrame_ ;
 const unsigned int nFramesToUse_ ;


} ;

 #include "MarkerSampler.inl"

#endif
```

.inl file

```
template <class MarkerT>
std::vector<MarkerSet<MarkerT> > MarkerSampler<MarkerT>::sample(const double scaleFactor, const double noiseSD)
{
....
}

template <class MarkerT>
MarkerSetVector MarkerSampler<MarkerT>::sample2(const double scaleFactor, const double noiseSD)
{
....
}
```

Comment: You cannot initialize the vectors inside the class definition, but need to do that in a constructor. What happens if you fix the vector declarations?

Comment: Sorry I am not quite with you. Could you point to the line you think is wrong please.

Comment: I am talking about the `sample` and `sample2`. In the class definition you can only declare them, but you initialize them (the stuff inside the parentheses).

Comment: You shouldn't use [reserved names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) for include guards (or for anything else).

Comment: Ups, these are functions, not objects. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing ; part of that error is slightly misleading, the compiler actually just doesn't recognize the `MarkerSetVector` type.  I think this is because it's typedef'd inside the `MarkerSampler` class.

If you explicitly state the scope of the typedef it should fix the error.  Though (depending on your compiler at least) you may also need to add in the `typename` keyword, since `MarkerSetVector` is a dependant type.  Here's a fixed example:

```
template <class MarkerT>
typename MarkerSampler< MarkerT >::MarkerSetVector MarkerSampler<MarkerT>::sample2(const double scaleFactor, const double noiseSD)
{
....
}
```

Comment: Nice - I was just typing that up (but would have missed the <MarkerT> before the ::, so it's good you beat me :).

Comment: For completeness: The standard states that arguments to the function are in the scope of the class of the method being defined, **but** the return type is not. That is, you cannot use unqualified `MarkerSetVector` as return type even if you can use it as an argument type. Now, in C++11 you can defer the return type to the end of the expression, where the scope of the class has already been entered and avoid qualification (I find this confusing so I would avoid it): `template <type T> auto MarkerSampler<T>::sample2(...) -> MarkerSetVector {...}` now the return is in the scope of the class.